# Haskell Pattern Matching

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
type Variable = String 
data Expr = T | Var Variable | And Expr Expr | Not Expr
```

The test case is as follows:

```
prop_v1 = v (Not (And (Var "y") T)) === ["y"]
```

What is the meaning of `data Expr` - is it just defining the types that can be input and their parameters? I.e. a `Var` takes a `Variable`, `And` takes two `Expr`'s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The datatype declaration for `Expr` gives rise, systematically, to a set of patterns which cover all possible things that a value of type `Expr` can *be*. Let's do the translation

```
data Expr           -- any e :: Expr must be one of
  = T               -- T
  | Var Variable    -- (Var x)         -- where x :: Variable
  | And Expr Expr   -- (And e1 e2)     -- where e1 :: Expr, e2 :: Expr
  | Not Expr        -- (Not e1)        -- where e1 :: Expr
```

You can see that the `T`, `Var`, `And` and `Not` that head up each `data` clause are **constructors**, and live in the value language; the rest of the things in each clause live in the type language, saying what type each component of an `Expr` must have. Each of the corresponding **patterns** consists of the constructor applied to **pattern variables** standing for components which have the given types. Basically, the patterns that show up on the left-hand side of a function are made by repeatedly refining pattern variables to the patterns that their values can possibly take, *as indicated by their type*.

Writing a function by pattern matching does not consist of saying what to *do*: it consists of saying what the output *is* for the possible cases of what the input *is*. You need to analyse the input into cases where you can easily say what the output must be. So, start with one general case...

```
v :: Expr -> [Variable]
v e = undefined
```

...and refine it. Ask "Can you tell what it is yet?". We can't tell what `v e` is without knowing more about `e`. So we'd better *split* e. We know that `e :: Expr`, so we know what patterns its value can match. Make four copies of your program line, and in each, replace `e` by one of the four possible pattern listed above.

```
v :: Expr -> [Variable]
v T           = undefined
v (Var x)     = undefined
v (And e1 e2) = undefined
v (Not e1)    = undefined
```

Now, in each case, can you tell what the output is? The handy thing is that you can make use of recursive calls on components. Assume you already know what `vars e1` and `vars e2` are when you're trying to say what `v (And e1 e2)` must be. If you get the steps right, the program will be correct.

I find it's often helpful to think in terms of concrete examples. Take your test example.

```
v (Not (And (Var "y") T))
```

That's supposed to be `["y"]`, right? Which pattern does it match?

```
Not e1   -- with e1 = And (Var "y") T
```

What's

```
v e1
```

? Looking at it, it had better be

```
["y"]
```

In this example, what's `v (Not e1)` in terms of `v e1`? The very same. That might suggest a suitable expression to replace `undefined` in

```
v (Not e1) = undefined  -- can you tell what this is now?
```

(Of course, a suggestive example is just a good start, not a guarantee of correctness.)

The takeaway messages: (1) build patterns by splitting pattern variables, figuring out the possible patterns by looking at the declaration of the type; (2) assume that recursive calls on components give you the right answer, then try to construct the right answer for the whole problem.

*Shameless plug: [shplit](http://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/~conor/pub/shplit) is a simple tool I built for my students, capturing message (1) mechanically.*

Comment: Your T and (Var x) cases look good to me. For (And e1 e2) and (Not e1), yes, e1 and e2 could be anything, but you're entitled to recursion on those components. In effect, you already know (v e1) and (v e2). Given those pieces of output, can you finish the job and assemble v (And e1 e2) and v (Not e1)? If so, then you've justified that recursion by explaining how the output is built up from the base cases, layer by layer.

Comment: This is going quite well, by the looks of things. Is there a particular order you want the variables in? I'm just wondering the purpose served by reverse. If you're supposed to be removing duplicates, union is indeed a useful tool: if you apply it to two lists without duplicates, you get a list without duplicates. Again, you can assume that you get good (whatever that means) answers recursively for the components when you're building a good answer for the whole thing.

Comment: There is no particular order I want the variables in. Hmm well, I put the reverse in as for some reason I thought it would "reverse" the result as required for the Not. Although I've realised that just reverses the order of the list, silly mistake!

Comment: I don't think that's entirely fair. There's a good (and to a lot of people, not at all natural) method for thinking about this sort of problem, and I think it's both possible and useful to teach that method.

Comment: This comment thread is shorter than I remember. Some remarks may have lost context.

Answer (score 5):

`data Expr` defines a new data type, specifying "constructors" like `Var` which takes a `Variable` or `And` which takes two expressions.

You can match against an `Expr` using these constructors:

```
fn (Var name)      = ...
fn (And exp1 exp2) = ...
...
```

Note that `data Expr = ...` only defines *one* type, `Expr`. `Var`, `And`...etc are all *constructors* of `Expr`, so a value like `Var "blarg"` will be of type `Expr`.

You should probably read the first couple chapters of [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com) to learn the basics.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at that resource a few times but I will definitely look over it again to try and get a better understanding of Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, how would I approach defining this function with pattern
>   matching?

Excuse me, but this is the wrong question.
This is like someone is asking "How would I approach matrix multiplication with array indexing?" (To which one could simply reply: Why, how do you do it *without* array indexing?)

You should ask "Given an Expr, how can I find all the variables that occur in it?" And then, the meaning of pattern matching unfolds itself automatically.

Your data type `Expr` is one possible representation of fairly simple boolean expressions. You have variables, a literal value `T` (that stands for `true` maybe - btw, are you sure you have not forgotten `F`?) and have that, if *x* is an Expression then so will be `Not` *x* and if *x* and *y* are expressions, then so will be `And` *x y*.

So, first, please describe precisely (not just: "I go from left to right and write down each variable name I find.") how to find all the variables in such an expression in your mothers language. For example: "If the expression is `T`, the list of variables occuring in that expression is empty." Be sure to cover all possible cases. Then come back and we will show you how to translate that into Haskell, but I am sure you will have noticed for yourself by then.